# Make part of the reference in italic

Tags: bibliographies

I want to put the title in italic, but it only prints out the author in italic. So I forced everything into normal text with this>

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\begingroup
\let\itshape\upshape
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{mybib}
\endgroup
```

But I want to put the title of the article in italic:

A minimum example should be:

> Laszlo Tabar, Ming-Fang Yen, Bedrich Vitak, Hsiu-Hsi Tony Chen, Robert
>   A Smith, and Stephen W Duy. "Mammography service screening and
>   mortality in breast cancer patients: 20-year follow-up before and
>   after introduction of screening". The Lancet, 361(9367):1405{1410,
>   April 2003.

I want to put:

> "Mammography service screening and mortality in breast cancer
>   patients: 20-year follow-up before and after introduction of
>   screening"

in italic like this:

> *"Mammography service screening and mortality in breast cancer patients: 20-year follow-up before and after introduction of
>   screening"*

Comment: Hi and welcome, we need a bit more information to be helpful here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).  In a standard document the title is italic not the author.

Comment: I recommend using the modern `biblatex` along with biber. Changing the appearance of the bibliography using the old system is cruel.

Comment: Johannes_B and Andrew Swann I already put a minimum example.

Comment: If you disable `\itshape`, you can't have italics. Are you sure the style prints the names in italics? It doesn't, according to my experience.

Answer (score 1):

The question really doesn't give enough information to provide a definitive answer, but some things can be offered.  Some comments suggest using a different bibliography program.  But if you wish to remain with bibtex, you can make a copy of the bibliography style (.bst file).  In this case, I rename `unsrt.bst` to `myunsrt.bst`.

Programming in BST language is arcane, but in the case of making something, italic, it amounts to adding the word `emphasize` following the field.  So, if the item in question is an `@ARTICLE`, then I edit the definition to add the word `emphasize` following `format.title`, as such:

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title emphasize "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { journal emphasize "journal" output.check
      format.vol.num.pages output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

Then, when I run the program

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}

@ARTICLE{myref,
  AUTHOR = "last, first",
  TITLE = "This is the title",
  JOURNAL = "The Lancet",
  YEAR = "2014"
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliographystyle{myunsrt}
\begin{document}
I will cite \cite{myref}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

I get the following output, with the title emphasized (italic in this case):

[image]